# ElasticSearch Error on Re-index

Tags: catalogsearch, magento2.4, elasticsearch, php-7.3

Every time I run the indexer - elastic search fails and the catalog search is never indexed. I am on Magento 2.4 CE with PHP7.3

```
Catalog Search index PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Wrong parameters for Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\ServerErrorResponseException([string $message [, long $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]]) in /var/www/vm/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:665
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vm/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(665): Exception->__construct(NULL, 503)
#1 /var/www/vm/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php(320): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process5xxError(Array, Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/vm/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(28): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array)
#3 /var/www/vm/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#4 /var/www/vm/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Core.php(341): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\CompletedFutureValue->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#5 /var/ww in /var/www/vm/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php on line 665
```

Comment: having a similar issue on 2.3.3. Do you happen to have a lot of data in your store? Like big catalog with thousands of products? Similar issue was reported on Magento github: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29454